# Core Data: how to check relationship existence?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I got this error: `Unable to parse the format string "createdBy.id = %@ && showAgain = false && like != nil`

`fr2.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "createdBy.id = %@ && showAgain = false && like != nil", liu.id!)`

problem is the last part: `like != nil` if I remove, it is ok. It is a `to-one` relationship. Why is it not possible to check its existence? What other way do you know?

Comment: like is a reserved word.  Try escaping it with #like instead.

Comment: serious, where are reserved words defined?

Comment: It's not easy to find: at the very bottom of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB) in the Predicate Programming Guide.

Comment: aaaa .. ok, got it